# wget command is not downloading csv file

Tags: csv, wget

i'm trying the wget command with the url below but it's not
downloading the CSV file correctly. Can anyone help with this?

https://www.statistik-berlin-brandenburg.de/opendata/AfSBBB_BE_LOR_Strasse_Strassenverkehrsunfaelle_2020_Datensatz.csv

Answer (score 0):

I used `--spider` option to reveal true type of file under link

```
wget --spider https://www.statistik-berlin-brandenburg.de/opendata/AfSBBB_BE_LOR_Strasse_Strassenverkehrsunfaelle_2020_Datensatz.csv
```

and was informed that

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 758 [text/html]
Remote file exists and could contain further links,
but recursion is disabled -- not retrieving.
```

so despite .csv in name it is html, that is probably page I then downloaded and inspected said page, it looks as follows

```
<!doctype html><html lang="de"><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/><meta name="generator" content="Amt fÃ¼r Statistik Berlin-Brandenburg"/><title>Seite wird geladen</title><link rel="preconnect" href="https://api.scrivito.com" crossorigin/><link rel="preconnect" href="https://api.scrivito.com"/><link rel="preconnect" href="https://cdn0.scrvt.com"/><script defer="defer" src="/assets/index.65d54663cbf0759e5371.js"></script><link href="/assets/index.0823cc0c27dde2848784.css" rel="stylesheet"><script src="/js_snippets_head.js"></script></head><body><div id="application"><span class="loader">Seite wird geladen ...</span></div></body></html>
```

So it seems to be page with JavaScript which does prompt browser to download file. GNU `wget` does not support JavaScript execution so is not right tool for your task, you might get desired file downloaded using some browser automation tool instead.